# Sqlite error while trying mvvmcross sample

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am very new to MvvmCross, and I'm watching N=12 - Start of Collect-A-Bull - N+1 days of MvvmCross 
I just finished what stuart did on YouTube.
But I got exception When I start my windows phone app.
I just attached screen shot of my error.

Please Help

Comment: Did you install the plugin into your WinPhone project as well? Most plugins need to be installed in the Core project as well as the platform project.

Comment: Also, which version of WindowsPhone are you developing on? WinRT/Jupiter or Silverlight?

Comment: Yes I installed SQLite plugin on windows phone app.

Comment: I am working on Windows phone 8.1. WinRT

Comment: If you are using WinRT, then you'll need to use the WindowsRuntime packages from SQLite - http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: @Stuart  I installed those extension sdks. but still doesn't work. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Added them to your project as well? I'm not an expert on windows phone Jupiter - might be worth asking the more general winphone and WinRT community -' hopefully they can help you out.

Comment: @Stuart Thanks for your advice. And I found what the problem was.  I installed extension sdk but it didn't work.  I had to add reference to SQLite for Windows phone 8.1 in add reference window separately and I need to change build platform to x86.  Thanks for your advice and great tutorial video from YouTube, I learned everyday from. Thanks!